# Converting Tensor product to Matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, tensors, output

I have a basic question regarding matrices and tensor product forms. Given $N > 0$, I am interested in the tensor product series $\sum_{i}^{N} X_i$, where $X_i$ is the Pauli $X$ spin operator at the i-th index.

Hence for $N=2$, I am interested in $X \otimes I + I \otimes X$.
To this end, consider

```
Id = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
SigX = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};

TensorProduct[SigX, Id] + TensorProduct[Id, SigX]
```

This yields a tensor product object of dimension 1 in Mathematica. How can I convert this into a matrix object of the form

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ (not just for presentation purposes) with dimensions 2x2. I obtain the correct entries as is but the object is a tensor product with submatrices. Can anyone advise on this, thanks.

Comment: `ArrayFlatten`  work.

Comment: Use [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) instead of [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct)